# ValueChanges event not triggered in first shot in Angular 6 - Reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have defined a function in my TypeScript file which subscribe to the ValueChanges feature of a form control in a reactive Form (Angular 6).

However I am calling this function in ngOnInit() method but somehow it is not going inside the service call within that method. And then when I go to my screen which contains the form control and start typing something, it does not return any result (as service call is not invoked) but if I blur from that formControl and again come back to that form control, and start typing, it return the result in second shot. Not clear what am I missing in the flow.

**myrequestComponent.ts**

```
searchUsersDetails() {
      console.log('Inside method');
      this.requestForm.controls.requestedFor.valueChanges.subscribe(
      term => {
        if (term !== '') {
            console.log('term::' + term);
          this.dataService.searchUsers(term).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.userDetails = data;
                const userNamesTmp = new Array(this.userDetails.length);
                this.userDetails.forEach(function (userDetailTmp) {
                    userNamesTmp.push(userDetailTmp.name);
                });
                this.userNames = userNamesTmp;
            });
        }
      });
  }
```

I am calling above method from ngOnInit() method in the typeScript file and FormControl in my html file:

```
 <td>
                    <kendo-autocomplete formControlName="requestedFor" class="form-control" placeholder="Type User" style="height:3.25rem" [data]="this.userNames" 
                       (blur)="this.populateOtherFields()" required >
                    </kendo-autocomplete>
                 </td>
```

Comment: a minimum reproducible example on stackblitz would be very helpful

Comment: The hook you need to use is ngOnInit and not ngInit.

Comment: sorry for typo. I am using on ngOnInit only.